# My code failed to read arabic values from res/values-ar/strings.xml

Tags: android, eclipse

I work on an android application on Eclipse IDE ,my goal is converting  textviews' texts and buttons' texts from  English to Arabic language  and vice verse.
I have on activity_main.xml two buttons  of Id Arabic & English
I have two folders /res/values for English values and /res/values-ar for Arabic values
When I press the English button the texts are converted to English language(the application reads from the default values folder /res/values/strings.xml).

But when I press Arabic button the texts remains as they are (they don't return back to Arabic language as expected).

These are my buttons on main_activity.xml file

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/English"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="بالانجليزي" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Arabic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="بالعربية" />
```

This is the activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    private Button English,Arabic;  
    private Locale myLocale;
    public void changeLang(String lang)
    {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    updateTexts();
    }

public void saveLocale(String lang)
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.commit();
}

public void loadLocale()
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

private void updateTexts()
{

 English.setText(R.string.English);
 Arabic.setText(R.string.Arabic);

}
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.English= (Button)findViewById(R.id.English);
    this.Arabic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Arabic);

 Button  english = (Button) findViewById(R.id.English);
 english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  String lang = "en";
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.English:
 lang = "en";
 break;
 case R.id.Arabic:
 lang = "ar";
 break;
 default:
 break;  
 }
 changeLang(lang);
 }
 });
 Button  Arabic= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Arabic);
 english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
 String lang = "ar";
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.English:
lang = "en";
break;
case R.id.Arabic:
lang = "ar";
break;
default:
break;  
}
changeLang(lang);
}  
});
}}
```

and this the default file values\strings.xml  (for storing English values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">كومتاس</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="green_color">#33CCFF</string>
<string name="application_title">كومتاس</string>
<string name="Life_Plus_Button">Life Palace</string>
<string name="Arabic">Arabic language</string>
<string name="English">English language</string>
</resources>
```

And this file for storing Arabic values  res\values-ar\strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources><string name="app_name">كومتاس</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="green_color">#33CCFF</string>
<string name="English">بالانجليزية</string>
<string name="Arabic">بالعربية</string>
<string name="Life_Plus_Button">لايف بلس</string>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling **English** `button` clicklistener twice. just need to fix your code on:

```
 Button  Arabic= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Arabic);
 English.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

TO:

```
 Arabic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

And i suggest in all xml files put this on top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

hope to be helpful